# how to chech rotation of a button

Tags: iphone, core-animation, uitableview

I am developing a app in which i have rotate a delete button when user clicks it as in contacts as follows

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];

    btn.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((0.0174532925)*90);

    //put the -ve sign before 30 if you want to rotate the button in the anticlockwise else use this one 

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    selectedRow=btn.tag;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

i want to reload the table when animation is completed how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotateButton" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myAnimDidStop:finished:context:)];
btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((0.0174532925)*90);
[UIView commitAnimations];
selectedRow = btn.tag;
```

The delegate method will look like:

```
- (void)myAnimDidStop:(NSString *)animID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void*)ctx {
    if ([@"rotateButton" isEqualToString:animID]) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Note that if you're targeting iOS 4 and newer, you could use animations blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{ 
                     btn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((0.0174532925)*90);
                     selectedRow = btn.tag;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
                     [self.tableView reloadData]; 
                 }];
```